# Problema con url de un archivo a cargar

Tags: java, archivo, javafx, webview

Estoy intentando cargar un archivo **HTML** en una ventana utilizando **JAVA** a través del siguiente código:

```
 public void showManual (ActionEvent event) {

    File myFile = new File("prueba/index.html");
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setTitle("Manual de ayuda");
    stage.setWidth(500);
    stage.setHeight(600);
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

    VBox root = new VBox();

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setContent(browser);
    webEngine.load(myFile.toURI().toString());

    root.getChildren().addAll(scrollPane);
    scene.setRoot(root);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

El sistema operativo que uso es Windows y lo que me devuelve el `myFile.toURI()` es esto `file:/E:/datos/proyecto/prueba/index.html` y al parecer no es una ruta válida.

¿Alguien me pudiera decir que poder hacer? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes creada la carpeta pruebas dentro de la raiz del proyecto o la creaste dentro del proyecto?

```
 File myFile = new File("prueba/index.html");
```

porque aquí llamas a buscar en la raíz la carpeta prueba

y asi:

```
File myFile = new File("/prueba/index.html");
```

llamarías a la carpeta dentro del mismo proyecto.
Siempre checa bien donde se encuentra cada carpeta o archivo y si no existe puedes hacer el mkdirs y así asegurar la creación de las carpetas correspondientes.

Comment: si prueba es un a carpeta dentro del proyecto, de la forma que me pones con el / delante lo que sale es file:/E:/prueba/index.html y ese no es el path completo

Comment: Pureba con el JFileChooser y ve el path completo, porque debe ser un problema de busqueda del archivo.